# Automatical serial numbering of overloaded functions in c#

Tags: c#, python, c++, comtypes

I implemented a COMtypes-API in c++. Most of the functions I use are overloaded (see examples below). Now when I call them from my unit test in c# they somehow get numbered, when I call them from python they do not. Can someone explain this? See below for the current (working) code:

```cpp
//declaration in c++ Header (QT)
bool function (string foo, int bar);
bool function (string foo);
bool function ();
```

```py
#calling from python (skript written with notepad++)
print Api.function("test", 1);
print Api.function("test");
print Api.function();
```

```cs
//calling from c# (Visual Studio)
bool result;
result = Api.function("test", 1); //first declared version works as usual
//result = Api.function("test"); doesn't work, instead I have to do
result = Api.function_1("test"); //for some reason THIS works
result = Api.function_2(); //counting up
```

At least it works in python (which is more important) but I'm still very curios why it doesn't work in c#

Comment: Is this a C# oder QT C++ question?

Comment: I honestly don't know. The API causing the issue is written in c++, the issue itself appears in c#. So what do you think?

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough and lacks at least a minimal reproducable example.

Comment: Well, a minimal reproducable example would have a lot of unnecessary stuff involved just to get things compiled properly. I hope that people with enough background know what I'm referring too here and can provide help. And I think the question is as clear as it gets: Why does A work and B doesn't? Or rather why does A work in one language but not in another?